# Port COM is not appear STM32F4 tinyUSB

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I'm trying to add tinyUSB library but I get this define CFG_TUSB_RHPORT1_MODE as not defined.With this [line](https://github.com/jadczakoff/Test_tinyUSB_v3/blob/638f9295a955c625eb1203bfbfc14faa0fa65cc0/Core/tinyUSB/portable/st/synopsys/dcd_synopsys.c#L528) I have problem. If i comment this line, my usb is not appear in device manager. I did this [tutorial](https://anvilelectronics.ovh/tinyusb-na-stm32-device-cdc/). Could you check what i'm doing wrong (link to repo below)?
At the end I want to make CDC communication without misc.

Answer (score 2):

Okey I solved issue. Silly I did't think to change number from 1 to 0... so it looks now:

```
if (!(rhport == 1 && (CFG_TUSB_RHPORT0_MODE & OPT_MODE_HIGH_SPEED))) usb_otg->GCCFG |= USB_OTG_GCCFG_PWRDWN;
```

and in tusb_config.h I added:

```
#define CFG_TUSB_MCU OPT_MCU_STM32F4
#define CFG_TUSB_OS OPT_OS_NONE
#define BOARD_DEVICE_RHPORT_SPEED OPT_MODE_FULL_SPEED
#define BOARD_DEVICE_RHPORT_NUM 0
#define CFG_TUSB_RHPORT0_MODE (OPT_MODE_DEVICE | OPT_MODE_FULL_SPEED)
```

Now its working :D Discussion can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with RHPORT1 in my case - STM32F407:

```
#define CFG_TUSB_RHPORT1_MODE (OPT_MODE_NONE)
```